# MediaWiki: Changing the root location

Tags: mediawiki

I have installed MediaWiki (mediawiki-1.17.0) on Ubuntu 11.04, and it appears to be working fine. However, the location of the wiki is www.mysite.com/mediawiki-1.17.0/ which is a bit cumbersome. Instead, I would like the location to be www.mysite.com/wiki/.

I have tried renaming the folder, but this causes some configuration issues that lead to the wiki not being found.

How do I change the location of the wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit your LocalSettings.php. In this file, go to the line no. 28 and change this to the below line:

```
 //$wgScriptPath       = "/mediawiki-1.17.0";
 $wgScriptPath       = "/wiki";
```

and change your folder name.

[Source](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php)